# No dependent module org.netbeans.api.templates

Tags: netbeans

Estoy contribuyendo con un módulo de NetBeans que me encontré en GitHub, actualicé los cambios y al tratar de correr me sale el siguiente mensaje:

```
Scanning for modules in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\nb
Scanning for modules in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\platform
Scanning for modules in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\apisupport
Scanning for modules in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\ide
Scanning for modules in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\java
Scanning for modules in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\profiler
Scanning for modules in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\harness
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\harness\build.xml:174: No dependent module org.netbeans.api.templates
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Lo más curioso es que al buscar en las dependencias si sale

[image: pantallazo]

Agradecería si alguien supiera como solucionarlo.

Comment: ¿A cuál módulo hace referencia?

Comment: org.netbeans.api.templates

Comment: Ruslan, Veo que tienes Netbeans 8.0.2 , has tratado con una versión mas actual, probablemente la versión 8.1.

Comment: Estoy trabajando con la version del plugin para 8.0.1, osea que si me paso a la 8.1 que tiene una semana, no podría generar un nbm compatioble apra la 8.0.1 ( que de hecho por el build que tengo es equivalente a la 8.0.2, pues creoq ue aún no hacen el update para la plataforma y el branding para convertir mi netbeans de 8.0.1 con actualizaciones a 8.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al hacer merge de los cambios se duplicaron las dependencias, bastó con borrar las que salía el `.jar` y no el nombre de la librería.